# TabularX - Fullwidth Table with Centered Text. Having issues

Tags: latex

I've tried many combinations. I am trying to get the text on this table to be centered in the cells and also keep it the full width of the page. Currently I have this.

```
            \begin{table}[h]
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|}
              \hline
              \rowcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}
              % START HEADER 
              \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\#}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Status}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Time}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Reason}}} \\ \hline
              % END HEADER

              % START Reason
              1 & \textbf{Open} & \today & Client Request \\ \hline
              % END Reason
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
```

Which results in the following. How can I update this to center the text.

[image: Table]

Comment: Please include a premarble so I know what packages I need to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new column type that combines X and `\centering` with the `array` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|Y|Y|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}
    % START HEADER 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\#}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Status}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Time}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C70F0F}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Reason}}} \\ \hline
    % END HEADER

    % START Reason
    1 & \textbf{Open} & \today & Client Request \\ \hline
    % END Reason
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This really helps. Also being able to see how you define new types!